# increase maximum data size from php to shell_exec

Tags: php, json

the code is passing JSON object from PHP to shell,

**code:**

```
$result =  shell_exec('<python script> 2>&1 '.escapeshellarg(<json_object>));
```

**Result:**

After some limit (JSON object has an array of (700x700) numbers) data did not get the pass to shell in my cases.

**problem**

can someone please tell me is there a way to increase this threshold? 
or I do have to find out a workaround

Comment: You could store it in a temp file using php which you then read using python?

Comment: seems to be this is the only way, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why this argument does not get pass to the script, it not because of the php or python limit it but Os it self has maximum argument size which apparently drop out the given argument if it is  larger than $MAX_ARG value .

**Solution**

change the code to get the argument piecewise rather than whole chunk .